# How am I missing reading some of the kafka messages?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Kafka topic with 3 partitions and I have only one consumer subscribed to that topic. Somehow I am missing reading some of the Kafka messages.

```
val prop = new Properties()
prop.setProperty("bootstrap.servers",kafkaServerPort)
prop.setProperty("group.id", "test-consumer-group")
prop.setProperty("flink.partition-discovery.interval-millis", "1000")

val testSource = KafkaSource.builder[String]
                              .setBootstrapServers(kafkaServerPort)
                              .setTopics("TestTopic")
                              .setProperties(prop)
                              .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.LATEST))
                              .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                              .build()
ingestCommon.sEnv.fromSource(tdiceSource, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "KafkaConsumer").setParallelism(1).name("KafkaConsumer")
```

Comment: How did you find that you are missing reading some messages? Is it through Kafka offsets of partitions not moving? or you think you are "skipping" messages?

Comment: We have logging enabled after we read the message from Kafka,  we put it in DB. Some messages I dont see in my db. I see before and after messages. My question is I have 2 partitions,  do I have to consume it with 3 parallels? or Do I need 3 different consumers?

Comment: When you say "before and after messages", are you sure that the messages are before and after the expected message in the same partition?

Comment: Maybe you're succeeding in reading the messages from Kafka, and failing to write them to the DB? How do you know where the problem is happening?